# Forward console output of npm / js file to powershell console

Tags: powershell

In my powershell script I do following:

```
Write-Host (npm run onesky_script -- "param1" "param2" "param3") -Separator `n
// OR following
npm run onesky_script -- "param1" "param2" "param3" | Write-Host
```

And I get following output in both cases in my powershell console:

```
> onesky@1.0.0 onesky_script C:\some\path
> node onesky.js "param1" "param2" "param3"

Some console output created by my js script via console.log
```

What I want is following output (ONLY the js script output, NOT the calls of the script):

```
Some console output created by my js script via console.log
```

Is there some calling syntax changes or alternative syntax I can use to achieve what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Write-Host is you are trying to use data you want to send to another item. Write-Host empties the buffer and is not pipeline friendly, if you are below PowerShellv5x. In v5, it now writes to the information stream. This has been documented by Microsoft for sometime now.

> http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful
>
> ... Jeffrey Snover change his stance on this as of May 2016.
>
> With PowerShell v5 Write-Host no longer "kills puppies". data is
>   captured into info stream ...
>
> https://twitter.com/jsnover/status/727902887183966208 ...
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1

Look to using the defined output redirects.

[About Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

> Examples

```
# Example 1: Redirect errors and output to a file
dir 'C:\', 'fakepath' 2>&1 > .\dir.log
```

> This example runs dir on one item that will succeed, and one that will
>   error.
>        It uses 2>&1 to redirect the Error stream to the Success stream, and > to send the resultant Success stream to a file called dir.log

```
# Example 2: Send all Success stream data to a file
.\script.ps1 > script.log
```

> This command sends all Success stream data to a file called script.log

```
# Example 3: Send Success, Warning, and Error streams to a file


&{
   Write-Warning "hello"
   Write-Error "hello"
   Write-Output "hi"
} 3>&1 2>&1 > P:\Temp\redirection.log
```

> This example shows how you can combine redirection operators to
>   achieve a desired result.
>
> • 3>&1 redirects the Warning stream to the Success stream.
>
> • 2>&1 redirects the Error stream to the Success stream (which also
>   now includes all Warning stream data)
>
> • > redirects the Success stream (which now contains both Warning and
>   Error streams) to a file called C:\temp\redirection.log)

```
# Example 4: Redirect all streams to a file
.\script.ps1 *> script.log
```

There are other output definitions / options in the link provided.